# Dynamic imported vue component failed to resolve

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

When I try to import a dynamic component with the import() function I receive following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
    return __webpack_require__("./src/components/types lazy recursive ^\\.\\/field\\-.*$")("./field-" + _this.type);
}
Reason: Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
```

Unfortunately I don't know what causes this error. I already tried to set the esModule to false inside the vue-loader config due to the [Release Notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.0.0).

I used vue-cli 2.9.2 with the webpack template to setup this project and this is the code of the actual component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="fieldType">
            <children/>
        </component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'DynamicComponent',
    props: {
        type: String,
    },
    computed: {
        fieldType () {
            return () => import(`./types/type-${this.type}`)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**[RESOLVED]**
The code above works. The issue was based on the `Loading chunk 0 failed` due to an edge case. With webpack setting `output: {publicPath: '/'}` it delivers the chunks relative to the root instead of its origin. When I embed the http://localhost:8080/app.js in my external server and called from there the import function the linked chunk url was http://myserver.com/0.js instead of http://localhost:8080/0.js. To fixed this I had to set `output: {publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'}` in the webpack configuration.

Comment: because `import()` is async.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is `import()` is **async** (it returns a **Promise**) which the error you got already told you:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component

Using a **watch** will be better like below demo (Inside `Promise.then()`, change componentType), then hook beforeMount or mounted to make sure props=type is intialized correctly.:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="componentType">
            <children/>
        </component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DefaultComponent from './DefaultComponent'

export default {
    name: 'DynamicComponent',
    components: {
        DefaultComponent
    },
    props: {
        type: String,
    },
    data: {
        componentType: 'DefaultComponent'
    },
    watch: {
        type: function (newValue) {
            import(`./types/type-${newValue}`).then(loadedComponent => { this.componentType = loadedComponent} )
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        import(`./types/type-${this.type}`).then(loadedComponent => { this.componentType = loadedComponent} )
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: But what calls the watch function? Because a prop doesn't change as well as the prop.type shouldn't change of course, because it is a prop?

Comment: use mounted() or beforeMount, when already mounted, get the componentType

Comment: Yes. I already tried that. Which avoids the resolving issue, but still doesn't load the chunks. I get this error with your code:

``Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 3 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete``

Comment: it seems like the path issue. adjust your path `.././types/type-${newValue}` or else then try again.

Comment: The path is correct so far. If I would change it (what I did) I will get a "Module not Found" error. I guess the issue is somewhere in the vue-cli configuration. I started with this [twitter post](https://twitter.com/DamianDulisz/status/903569400095285248).

Comment: It was not the exact solution to my problem, anyway your example leads to the right cause and shows an alternative of this use case besides other online resources. Thank you.

Comment: This answer might be outdated or just an alternative. At this point in time I think it's rather confusing because as @kindisch wrote his example works. Maybe an update of that question or a seperate answer could clear things up.